# eigenvectors from numpy.eig not orthogonal

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

my problem is the following: using scipy.linalg.eig to get eigenvectors and eigenvalues i see that all my eigenvalues have multiplicity 1 yet when i run the code below it doesn't confirm that the eigenvectors are orthogonal as they should be in this case. any reason why this would be? or how to fix it?

```
import scipy as SP
import numpy as NP
from scipy import linalg
from numpy import linspace,asscalar,argsort
import cmath
import time

matA=SP.array([[-0.0001, 0., 0., 0.00001, 0., 0., 0.00002, 0.],[0., -0.0002, 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],[0., 0., -0.00015, 0., 0., -9.*10**-6, 
  0., -0.00005],[0.00001, 0., 0., -0.0001, 0., 0.00001, 1.*10**-6, 
  0.],[0., 0., 0., -5.*10**-6, -0.0001, 0., 0., 0.],[0., -9.*10**-6, 
  0., 0.00001, 0., -0.0002, 0., 0.00005],[0., 0., 0., 0.00002, 0., 
  0., -0.0001, 0.],[0., 0.00004, 0., 0., 0., 0.00005, 0., -0.00015]])

matB=SP.array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],[0., 0., 1.5*10**-10, 0., 0., 0., 
  0., 0.],[0., -1.5*10**-10, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],[0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0.],[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3.*10**-10, 0., 0.],[0., 0., 
  0., 0., -3.*10**-10, 0., 2.*10**-10, 0.],[0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0., -2.*10**-10, 0., 0.],[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

matdim=len(matB[0])

#coefficient matrix for original ODE
def matM(x):
    return matA+(x**2)*matB

#define sorted eigensystem function
def eigsys(x):
    evs,EVS=linalg.eig(matM(x),check_finite=False)
    absevs=abs(evs)
    idx=argsort(absevs)[::-1]
    evs=evs[idx]
    EVS=EVS[:,idx]
    return (evs,EVS)

#check for orthogonality
eigvecs=SP.transpose(eigsys(60000)[1])
for j in range(8):
    for i in range(8):
        print SP.vdot(eigvecs[i],eigvecs[j])

#show eigenvalues all have multiplicity 1
print eigsys(60000)[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Why should they be orthogonal? Your matrix

```
a=matM(60000)
```

is far from being symmetric,

```
abs(a-a.T).max() -> 2.16
```

with

```
abs(a).max() -> 1.08
```

so I wouldn't necessarily expect orthogonal eigenvectors. Is it possibile that the function `matM` or the data `matA` or `matB` is wrong?

Comment: `matA` and `matB` are not quite symmetric.

Comment: well, `linalg.eig()` is called on `matM(60000)`, so `matA,matB` can be non-symmetric as long as `matM(60000)` is symmetric.

Comment: the matrix M doesnt have to be symmetric, the only condition for orthogonal eigenvectors is that all the eigenvalues are different from eachother right??

Comment: @AlanMorningstar: No, that's not correct.  Distinct eigenvalues do not imply orthogonal eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

As many others quoted, distinct eigenvalues do not guarantee eigenvectors are orthogonal.

But we have 2 special types of matrices
 **Symmetric matrices and Hermitian matrices**.

Here the eigenvalues are guaranteed to be real and there exists a set of orthogonal eigenvectors (even if eigenvalues are not distinct).

In `numpy`,

```
numpy.linalg.eig(any_matrix)
```

returns eigenvalues and eigenvectors for any matrix (eigen vectors may not be orthogonal)

And we have built-in functionality **to find orthogonal eigenvectors** for Symmetric and Hermitian matrix.

```
eigen_values, eigen_vectors = numpy.linalg.eigh(symmetric_matrix)
```

**Note**: 
`numpy.linalg.eigh` will consider only the upper triangular part or lower triangular part of the matrix to calculate eigenvalues (one part is like the mirror image of the other for these special matrices).

So if you pass a matrix which is neither symmetric nor Hermitian to get orthogonal eigenvectors, it will construct a symmetric matrix (not actually constructed, just for our understanding) with lower triangular part of the matrix and return eigenvalues and eigenvectors (they are orthogonal!) of this new matrix. So the answer will be wrong!

For more details, please refer

- [Eigen values of symmetric matrices](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/eigen/eigen.html?viewType=Print&viewClass=Print)
- [numpy.linalg.eigh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html#numpy.linalg.eigh)