# Are the eigenvectors returned in numpy.linalg.eig orthogonal?

Tags: numpy, scipy, eigenvalue, eigenvector, orthogonal

Are the eigenvectors returned in `numpy.linalg.eig` orthogonal? If not, how can I get orthogonal and normalized eigenvectors and relative eighenvaules?

I tried some simple example myself, in general, `v0*v1=0.0001xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, can I treat this result as orthogonal?

Comment: Can you provide a test example showing the problem?

Comment: Orthogonal eigenvectors are guaranteed for Symmetric and Hermitian matrices only.
Please refer this answer for more details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60448975/5774004

Answer (score 2):

Documentation for `numpy.linalg.eig` clearly states:

> The array v of eigenvectors may not be of maximum rank, that is, some of the columns may be linearly dependent, although round-off error may obscure that fact. If the eigenvalues are all different, then theoretically the eigenvectors are **linearly independent.**

However, they are not required to be **orthogonal**.

Comment: Calling `orth` here makes no mathematical sense.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right but it was not clear to me what OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: I try to solve a matrix differential equation, so I wanna diagonalize the matrix and get normalized and orthogonal eigenvectors and eigenvaules.

Comment: @kinderchan I think you may be mis-understanding what you need to do. To diagonalize a matrix using eigenvectors - see https://yutsumura.com/how-to-diagonalize-a-matrix-step-by-step-explanation/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064229/how-to-diagonalize-this-matrix/1064245 In very limited circumstances eigenvectors are orthogonal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Principal_component_analysis but normally they are *only* linearly-independent.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the eigenvectors returned in numpy.linalg.eig orthogonal?

NumPy does not make any such promise.

> If not, how can I get orthogonal and normalized eigenvectors and relative eighenvaules?

There is no guarantee the eigenspaces of a matrix are even orthogonal; it may not be possible to choose orthogonal eigenvectors.